# Safari <input type="file" accept="video/*"> ignores mp4 files

Tags: video, file-io, safari, attributes, mp4

I am using an HTML file input like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
```

to allow my users to upload videos to my site. This works as expected in all modern browsers (only permitting the user to select video files) except Safari.

From what I can tell Safari seems to interpret the `accept="video/*"` attribute as `accept="*.mov"` ignoring most, if not all, other video formats / extensions (webm, m4v, etc).

Any suggestions on how to get the select dialog to allow only common video filetypes (not just .mov's) in Safari?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

I found that the following accept string will add mp4 and m4v to the list of file types that safari will accept:

```
accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"
```

I'm not sure what the mime type is for webm videos but if you can look that up you should be able to tack it on to the accept string. The trick is to specify the mime type, just using a file extension won't work.

Comment: @gstackoverflow maybe you want video/quicktime

Comment: For m4a audio files, I had to use accept="audio/x-m4a,audio/*"

Answer (score 11):

You can take a look at webkit source code [~/Source/WebCore/platform/MIMETypeRegistry.cpp](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/MIMETypeRegistry.cpp).

These types are customized by Apple for Safari, and may not be working on other browsers.