# html accept attribute working differently on different operating systems

Tags: html, windows, macos, electron

Does the accept attribute for an input of file type work differently per operating system?

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*"  />
```

On a mac computer this limits so that only a video type file can be chosen. But on windows it still allows you to select anything.

Is there different syntax that must be used per operating system? Or am i over looking something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What browser engine is it using on Windows?

Comment: I am using Electron

Comment: I know that.  You'll get a lot more people able to help if you can say what browser engine it's using on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could possibly be with a browser compatiablity issue make sure whatever browser your using is up to date.

Another way of doing this would be to state the file types of what you are willing to accept.

Some links that could be useful:

[Safari <input type="file" accept="video/*"> ignores mp4 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107685/safari-input-type-file-accept-video-ignores-mp4-files)

[How to make <input type="file"/> accept only these types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293861/how-to-make-input-type-file-accept-only-these-types)