# How can I check the extension of a file upload within a multi-input form?

Tags: javascript, html

I request the user to upload 4 different files when they fill in the form.

Here is an example of one of the inputs:

```
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" accept="video/*" id="video1" required>
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="video1"> drop the video</label>
  </div>
```

I want the user to select an mp4 file type only. In the event they choose the wrong file type, I want a box to appear. I don't want this box to appear on the form submission which is what all the solutions on the net appear to solve.

Instead, when the user browses for a file, chooses the file and then clicks "open", I want a box to appear to tell the user to choose a file with the approved extension.

Is there a way to do this instead of at the point of submitting the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107685/safari-input-type-file-accept-video-ignores-mp4-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to show any alerts you can simply change the input tag as follow

```
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" id="video1" required>
```

If you really want to show a message you can call the alert by using oninput attribute. Try following

```js
 function inputHandler(value)
      {
       if(!value.endsWith("mp4"))
       {
           alert("only mp4 is allowed");
       }
      }
```

```html
<div class="custom-file">
      <input
        type="file"
        class="custom-file-input"
        accept="video/*"
        id="video1"
        required
        oninput="inputHandler(this.value)"
      />
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="video1"> drop the video</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: If the alert occurs and I click ok - how can I amend the script to auto clear the input field/?