# filepond doesn't work with video/* type in safari

Tags: filepond

i'm using [FilePond library](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/#:%7E:text=The%20File%20Type%20Validation%20plugin,interpret%20the%20accept%20attribute%20value.) in react, which works fine in chrome, but not in safari.
my issue is :

when i set `acceptedFileTypes={['video/*']}`

1. in chrome - it accepts all video types.
2. in safari - it will only accept `mov` files, and not all video type files.

when i set `acceptedFileTypes={['video/mp4']}` : it does the expected behaviour on both, and accepts only mp4 files.

i don't wish to set all possible video types, and would like to use the `video/*` filter.

**Safari version : 13.1.1**

```
<FilePond
  ref={fileRef}
  files={files}
  allowMultiple={false}
  labelIdle={labelIdle}
  className="video"
  instantUpload={false}
  onupdatefiles={(items) => {
    setFiles(items)
  }}
  onremovefile={() => toggleDisplayProgress(false)}
  acceptedFileTypes={['video/*']}
  required
/>
```

i can set the video types specifically here - https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/MIMETypeRegistry.cpp as described [in this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323498)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up using `quicktime` and `mp4`, which worked :

`acceptedFileTypes={['video/quicktime', 'video/mp4']}`.

There's no way to use the `video/*` on safari.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't all detect files in the same manner. Depending on the OS this might differ. The `fileValidateTypeDetectType` hook helps detect the right type. You can use it to manually set the right type based on (for example) the file extension.

```js
FilePond.create(document.querySelector('input'), {
    acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png'],
    fileValidateTypeDetectType: (source, type) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        // Do custom type detection here and resolve promise

        resolve(type);
    })
});
```

See: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/#custom-type-detection